# why "no temporary std::string objects would arise" said in Item 25 of Effective Modern C++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

In Item 25(170p~171p) of Effective Modern C++, the code is showed below:

```
class Widget {
public:
void setName(const std::string& newName) // set from
{ name = newName; } // const lvalue
void setName(std::string&& newName)     // set from
{ name = std::move(newName); }          // rvalue
…
};

w.setName("Adela Novak");
```

> With the version of setName taking a universal reference, the string
>   literal "Adela Novak" would be passed to setName, where it would be
>   conveyed to the assignment operator for the std::string inside w. w’s
>   name data member would thus be assigned directly from the string
>   literal; **no temporary std::string objects would arise**.

I dont't understand why "*no temporary std::string objects would arise*" if the version of setName taking a universal reference, is called. Shouldn't the **newName** be created as the a temporary std::string?

Comment: You must be looking at the wrong example. Your code is not using universal references.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Also, there's no "universal reference" in the code shown.

Comment: Universal reference overload would look something like `template <typename String> setName(String&& newName) { name = std::forward<String>(newName); }`

Comment: @inf  I know what you mean. The version of taking universal references should be the “void setName(T&& newName)”. Thanks.

Comment: @foo but it's not. That's a different thing. It's taking an rvalue as the comment suggests.

Comment: I think you'll need to send Scott an email for clarification.  Either he did not express himself well, or he had one too many beers before writing that item.

Comment: "More Effective C++" is from 1996 and I don't think there's a new edition, so there shouldn't be rvalue references in there. Did you mean "Effective Modern C++"?

Comment: Must be an error in the book. Which version of the book is this? Did you check the errata list?

Comment: @interjay Indeed, the book is called "Effective Modern C++".

Comment: @interjay Ron Sorry, I have edited

Comment: In the book, Meyers is referring to the first `setName` example, where he uses "universal references". The code OP has included is the example that does _not_ have "universal references".

Comment: Errata:  https://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html

Answer (score 5):

The code is preceded by

> ```
> template<typename T>
> void setName(T&& newName)             // newName is
> { name = std::forward<T>(newName); }  // universal reference
> ```

Later comes the code that you copied into your question. Then, before your quoted text:

> That would certainly work in this case, but there are drawbacks. [...] For example, consider this use of `setName`:
>
> ```
> w.setName("Adela Novak");
> ```

And immediately afterwards:

> With the overloaded versions of `setName`, however, [...]

The text is saying that no temporary string objects would arise in other code than what you quoted. You're severly misreading and as a result misquoting the text.

Answer (score 2):

Name of Item 25 is the following: **Use `std::move` on rvalue references, `std::forward` on universal references.**

The code you provided doesn't include version of `setName` with universal references. It is like this:

```
template <class T>
void setName(T&& t) {
    name = std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

This version will avoid creation of temporary.

Answer (score 0):

w.setName("Adela Novak");

**With Universal Reference:** ( void setName(T&& t) )
"Adela Novak" is a character array. hence the function template( void setName(T&& t) )is instantiated as (Widget::setName<char const (&)[11]>) template function.
Hence no conversion is required. No Temporary object is required.

**With Overloaded Function:** void setName(std::string&& newName)
The character array has to be converted into a std::string object(Temporary) before passing on to the setName(std::string&& newName) since the setName(std::string&& newName) expects only the std::string type.